# Adding searchable tags in a table

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTable with enabling the search feature. I want to know if I can insert tags inside the HTML of the rows, so these tags can be searchable. But I don't want them to appear in the front-end.

Currently am doing this, using **hidden attribute** or **display: none;**

I believe it's not the correct way to go about it, my biggest concern if it's affect how bots and SEO reads it, or it doesn't matter?

```
<tr>
    <td>Column 1 <span hidden>12th Sunday</span></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
</tr>
```

Can I do it in an attribute like this:

```
<tr>
    <td data-search-tag="12th Sunday">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to achieve it with attribute, or is there another way specified by the plugin to do it?

Comment: Search engines evidently can spot and penalize this kind of behavior. Why don't you try to find a way to make this content part of the table?

Comment: I would if that was an option, table contains lots of data, some are used as header rows duplicating them is not an option in my implection thats why I need to add them as hidden tags, to improve on the experience when searching.

Comment: Yes, you can use orthogonal data or data-* attributes which DT wil search for instead of the content in columns. I doubt any search engine index or even consider content of elements data attributes.

Comment: @davidkonrad I tried that, but text in attributes are not searchable, is there a way to enable that by the plugin? I am using the latest DT 1.10.18

Comment: @Kash how many monthly users do you expect for this app? This sounds like premature optimization to me...

Comment: ...And, can certainly not see why DataTables should be involved here, DT *hides* mostly content... If you have a huge static table on the page that would be indexed, but not be indexed more or better by any kind of DT "trick".